# Will St. Lucia customs hassle me about vitamins?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, caribbean, saint-lucia

I am traveling to St. Lucia for my wedding and was told by my future mother-in-law that I would not be allowed to take my vitamins with me, as customs would take any pills not in prescription bottles.

I have searched for the customs rules regarding this and have come up empty on any official site. The offical (?) [St. Lucia website's customs section](http://stlucianow.com/travel/information#CustomsRegulations) talks about exporting duty-free booze and non-Cuban cigars.

Comment: I am pretty sure natural (more healthy) vitamins are abundant on St. Lucia

Answer (score 2):

The website you are quoting does not look very "official". The official website of Saint Lucia's customs department is [www.customs.gov.lc](http://www.customs.gov.lc/)

On that site you will find a list of the [prohibited imports](http://www.customs.gov.lc/travellers.php#pro_imports). Vitamins are not explicitly listed, but there is a forbidden item called "narcotic drugs". Depending on your "vitamins" an officer might consider them as narcotic drugs and confiscate them ... If you want to be sure, you can always try to [contact the customs department](http://www.customs.gov.lc/contactus.php).